# Grouping Java classes

Tags: java, eclipse, class, package, explorer

When I'm using Eclipse i work with lots of Java classes (especially when working with abstract factory design pattern) and I need a way to visually group classes belonging together (different classes extended or implemented from interfaces get mixed together).

I need a way to group classes that extend the same class or implement the same interface so I don't lose my mental health. I started using Eclipse and Java few day ago, so I'm sure I'm missing something to do what i need...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you organized your classes in [packages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_package)? This is precisely what packages are for. If you organize them in packages, you'll have a nice view of the classes belonging together in the Eclipse *Package Explorer*.

Further reading:

- [The Java Tutorials: Creating and Using Packages](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/packages.html)

Answer (score 2):

Import the classes into a UML tool of some kind.   There are several free ones out there, including JUDE.  Or see if Eclipse has a UML plug-in.

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse has a very handy feature which allows you to see exactly which classes extend (or implement) any class/interface.

Select the superclass/interface/method you are interested in, and press CTRL-T. This will show a popup dialog with the implementing or extending class hierarchy. CTRL-T again will show the super class hierarchy (reverse direction)

Answer (score 1):

You can organize your classes belonging to same event into different packages.for example: com.abc.birds should contain classes related to birds only.com.abc.human should contain all classes related to human only.